# Tor relay loading informations

Tags: relays, exit-relays, directory

i've recently decided to support Tor throught a new relay, then i taked one of my server with debian 8 and follow the steps on torproject website after installing the most recently tor i've edited the torrc file uncommenting this:

```
ORPort 9001
DirPort 9030
Exitpolicy accept *:*
Nickname RELAYNAME
ContactInfo INFO@RELAYNAME
BandwidthRate 60 MBytes
BandwidthBurst 60 MBytes
```

after that i simply restarted the Tor service and checked the log:

```
Oct 18 19:24:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Oct 18 19:24:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Oct 18 19:24:13.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Oct 18 19:24:13.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Oct 18 19:24:13.000 [notice] Now checking whether ORPort x.x.x.x:9001 and DirPort x.x.x.x:9030 are reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
Oct 18 19:24:14.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent.
Oct 18 19:24:15.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your DirPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
Oct 18 19:24:15.000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
```

And after atleast 45mins my relay appeared on Atlas, now i've tried to connect throught my server to Tor simply adding`EntryNodes RELAYNAME`, but Tor cannot connect to Tor network and still remain in  `Loading relay informations`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs some more time and - if your relay is not having a Guard flag - it's role is not an EntryGuard, so try using `UseEntryGuards 0` with `EntyNodes {your relay}` **and** `StrictNodes 1` - and post a log if you will still have an error

Comment: LoL during this time i've tried to stop the process and stopped tor@default too but now it cannot be started again....im in panic..

Comment: this is what i obtain if i do `service tor@default restart`: Job for tor@defaults.service failed. See 'systemctl status tor@defaults.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Comment: so post your 'systemctl status tor@defaults.service' and 'journalctl -xn' output, please

Comment: systemctl: ● tor@default-service.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (instance default-service)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor@.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: and journalctl?

Comment: its too long and i cannot post it

Comment: use pastebin.net or add it to your question(that's better)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nm9RYSGu this is the journal

Comment: "Oct 19 00:09:35 MYSERVER tor[25456]: Oct 19 00:09:35.480 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports." - check your `torrc` and - please post it too, so we can checki it together

Comment: in my question i posted my actually torrc

Comment: torrc of the tor instance throught which one you're about to connect. As far as I've got you - this is the one which is failing

Comment: this is the torrc file of my relay server and this is the only one

Comment: your relay seems to be OK - according to your log. To exit *through* your relay you need to use a separated tor process/instance

Comment: ok tell me where is the file you wanna read

Comment: kk. let we pass through some Q&A session, then. So - your *first* instance with torrc and log you've provided in your question is running OK and fine, right?

Comment: yes it seems to be correct

Comment: Where from you're trying to connect *through* your relay we've discussed upstrings?

Comment: bro thanks for the support but i shall format this damned server..

Comment: it's not a server issue I think! You need to tune-up your *second* tor instance which is intended to be connecting through your first one. Give it a try ;)

Comment: Worth noting that `UseEntryGuards 0` isn't required (and is almost always a bad idea).

Comment: Also, don't use `systemctl` directly, manage it throught `service`, e.g. `service tor reload`. Using `systemctl` directly on LSB distros seems to cause confusion.

Comment: @canonizingironize sometimes when his relay is not obtained a "Guard" flag it is required to `UseEntryGuards 0` - saw it myself about a year ago: tor had 3 pre-specified entries, but only one of them has a "Guard" flag and was actually used(looking through connections/circuits monitor) - non-guards were completely ignored, until the useentryguards was set to zero: after that tor used all three entries and them only, so no risks were so far.

Comment: Cool story, bro. Anyway, it's not needed in this case and it's harmful. I know you like to put users at risk but I'm still going to suggest you shouldn't.

Comment: In strict nodes case with entry nodes specified in 96 hours tor haven't used any entrance except specified, and I'll repeat the experiment to check if it's still needed to disable entry guard usage if specific non-guard nodes are set to be an entry. It would be great if there's no need to do so now, I agree with you in this particular case by 100%!